ссылка это тип данных?
Является ли ссылка типом данных в языке с++, просто то определение типа с которым можно познакомится на просторах интернета звучит приблизительно как "множество значений(иногда пишут про состояния атрибутов) и операций над ними, вроде как ссылка в языке с++ является, как говорят, синтаксическим сахаром, и под это определение не попадает, но где то я видел жестко спорили(уже не вспомню где), буду рад если поясните, ну или отошлете на нужный источник
правильно ли говорить что ссылка в с++ - это не тип данных?

Ссылка - это тип, для нее даже трейт есть соотв. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_reference

Можно быть одновременно синтаксическим сахаром и типом. :) "под это определение не попадает" А почему нет? Множество значений = множество возможных адресов, на которые ссылка может указывать. Операция над ним - получение значения по адресу.

@HolyBlackCat Я поэтому и хотел уточнить, ведь определение "Множество значений = множество возможных адресов, на которые ссылка может указывать. Операция над ним - получение значения по адресу"  больше к указателям подходит понятное дело что у ссылки он под капотом, но я снаружи только вижу и никаких операций над сслыкой у меня нет, так как взятие значения я лично не выполняю, и вообще с этим значением никак не работаю

Есть два разных понятия: ссылка и ссылочный тип. В int& x имя x обозначает ссылку (не тип и не объект) с ссылочным типом int& (здесь "ссылка на int" - уже тип, а не ссылка или объект).

И, в частности, ни ссылка ни ссылочный тип не являются синтаксическим сахаром, если под этим понимать "другой синтаксис для одной семантики". https://stackoverflow.com/a/31286807/6944845

Стандарт C++20

6.8.1.  Types describe objects (6.7.2), references (9.3.3.2), or functions (9.3.3.5).


6.8.10. A type is a literal type if it is: ... a reference type


6.8.2 Compound types

Compound types can be constructed in the following ways:
— references to objects or functions of a given type, 9.3.3.2. There are two types of references: (1.4.1) — lvalue reference (1.4.2) — rvalue reference


Этого достаточно, чтобы считать ссылки полноценным составным типом?
